How to use create_pandas_dataframe_agent in langchain to pass any custom variable in prompt
I have a Datarame and want to query it using langchain create_pandas_dataframe_agent. However I want to pass one dynamic variable with the prompt.
For example:
df has columns department, salary, manager_name, emp_name.
I want to find top 3 manager names for the department "CSE". So I need to pass the department name as variable in the prompt ("Find top 3 manager names for ). Please guide me how can I do that.
I have tried passing the variable in format string like we do in python using {{}} but it didn't work out.
Any hint will be much appreciated.

Prompt template seems the way to do that. With single {} quote style.
See: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/composition
and or https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/partial
